# PHP programming in linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, development-environment

Which directory should I choose for my PHP projects? Should I use ~/public_html in my home directory or should I choose /var/www and change the owner to have write permissions? What would you recommend?

Comment: I believe /var/www is the default directory. Also if you're going to use /var/www make sure ownership is given to www-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer doing development in my home directory since I think that is where user files should be placed. But this is a personal choice, do what you think is best and/or easiest to configure. It should not matter that much.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using something like ~/development/php in my home dir, and then I either add symlink into /var/www or declare a virtual host in Apache pointing to my directory.

Comment: How do you declare a virtual host?

Comment: This is my same configuration (~/src/projectname and then a symlink in /var/www/ or /srv/www/)

Comment: Depending of your setup, it configured in httpd.conf or vhosts.conf or a similar file. The syntax is explained in Apache docs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `/var/www` is the default directory. Also if you're going to use `/var/www` make sure ownership is given to `www-data`

Answer (score 0):

It's good idea to put as little as possible of your source code in web-accessible places  ( /var/www ) so that if your machine is misconfigured your source isn't public.